# Migrating Data to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, informix

I am trying to migrate data from an Informix database to SQL Server 2008.  I've got quite a lot of data to move. I've been try multiple methods to get the data over, and so far SQLBulkCopy in multiple chunks seems to be the fastest that I can find. Does anyone know of a faster means of getting the data over? I'm trying to cut down on the transfer time so that on my cut-over date I don't run out of time to do the full cut-over.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, I think that the bcp command is the fastest solution.
you can make csv file from your data and then import those to your db by bcp command.

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot make a cvs file as the table has binary data.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much more you can do to get this work completed faster.  One thing you might want to look at though is the recover model for the sql database.  If it's currently set to Full, you're going to end up slowing down quite a bit as the transaction log fills up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an Ole or ODBC connection to your Informix database, then SSIS may be the best option.